# IE11 opening new tab instead of new window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Recently I upgraded my browser to IE11, after that it is opening new pages in new tabs.

I am using target=_blank in the form and when I submit the form using document.formname.submit(), IE11 opening new tab instead of new window. It is working fine in IE8.

Please let me know what might be the issue.

Comment: Why be so cruel to open a new window upon submitting a form?!?

Comment: Browsers generally allow the user to configure the browser such that new windows open one way or another. Your code cannot override settings like that.

Comment: I agree with @austinwernli, but if you must open it in a new window, you'll have to use [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).